# two web services SOAP not working with wildfly 9.0.2

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wildfly

So i have one SOAP application which works fine with Wildfly another one earlier was built on apache cxf and was running on tomcat but i had to make it work with Wildfly so i added a Jboss-deployment-structure as below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> <jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">   <deployment>
 <exclude-subsystems>
    <subsystem name="webservices" />
</exclude-subsystems>    </deployment>   </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

After which both web services started working on same wildfly but i noticed that if deployed they work but when the server is **restarted** the One which was working fine with Jboss  gives below error where as the Apache Cxf one is working fine.

```
2017-12-21 04:20:09,856 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /booking/ReservationService: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl (Module "deployment.CreateWS.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:437)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:269)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/dom/DocumentImpl
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:353)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:432)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DocumentImpl from [Module "deployment.CreateWS.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
    ... 66 more
```

where booking is the WS working with jboss and CreateWS is apache cxf one.

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.jboss.org/thread/201749

Comment: I resolved the issue by adding a manifest.mf file in META-INF folder with depedency to the webservice which stopped working and so whenever the server is restarted the old WS is loaded first and deployed.

Comment: I have a question is it possible to ignore the dependency if not found ?

Comment: You're making your life more difficult than it needs to be by using CXF, even when using Tomcat. Your JDK has a perfectly good JAX-WS implementation which allows you to implement web services with no library dependencies at all

Comment: yes but this is an old application so i cannot change much, the one which is newly created works with jax-ws.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by adding a manifest.mf file in META-INF folder with depedency to the webservice which stopped working and so whenever the server is restarted the old WS is loaded first and deployed.